# InvocationTargetException in spark job test scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I was trying to write scala test cases for my sparkJob but its not working, and giving InvocationTargetException.

I am trying to create new sqlContext and read a json file from my localbox.
I am using eclipse.

```
sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

the full exception is :

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constrructor.java:423) at
> org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:67)
> at
> org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:60)
> at
> org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:73)
> at
> org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.(TorrentBroadcast.scala:80)
> at
> org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
> at
> org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager..scala:63)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1318) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1006)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1003)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkCContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:700) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.hadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:1003) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.appply(SparkContext.scala:818)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:816))
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:700) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.texxtFile(SparkContext.scala:816) at
> com.databricks.spark.csv.util.TextFile$.withCharset(TextFile.scalaa:30)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource$$anonfuun$createRelation$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:146)
>
> at
> com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource$$anonfun$createRelation$1.apply(DDefaultSource.scala:146)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine$lzycompute(CsvRelation.scalaa:265)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine(CsvRelation.scala:263)
> at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.tokenRdd(CsvRelation.scala:89)
> at
> com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRRelation.buildScan(CsvRelation.scala:173)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$4.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:60)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$4.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:60)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:279)
>
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrattegy.scala:278)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:3100)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:274)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:556)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sqll.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.planLater(QueryPlanner.scala:54)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies$AAggregation$.apply(SparkStrategies.scala:235)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.pllanning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlaanner.scala:58)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecuution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:920)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:918)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:924)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:924)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
> at
> org.apache..spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1904)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1385)) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.count(DataFrame.scala:14033) at
> com.amazon.smt.ec.datapopulator.common.DataFrameOperationsTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(DataFrameOperationsTest.scala:55)
> at
> com.amazon.smt.ec.datapopulator.common.DataFrameOperatiionsTest$$anonfun$1.apply(DataFrameOperationsTest.scala:47)
>
> at
> com..amazon.smt.ec.datapopulator.common.DataFrameOperationsTest$$anonfun$1.apply(DataFrameOperationsTest.scala:47)
> at
> org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
> at
> org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
> at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85) at
> org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104) at
> org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22) at
> org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20) at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSuuiteLike.scala:158) at
> org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1121) at
> org.scalatest.FunSuite.withFixture(FunSuite.scala:1559) at
> org.scalatest.FuunSuiteLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FunSuiteLike.scala:155)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:167)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.sscala:167)
> at orrg.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306) at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTest(FunSuiteLike.scala:167) at
> org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTestt(FunSuite.scala:1559) at
> org.scalatest..FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:200)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:200)
> at
> org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traaverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
>
> at
> org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(LList.scala:318) at
> org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401) at
> org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
> at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:483) at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.runTests(FunSuiteLike.scala:200) at
> org.scalatest.FunSuite.runTests(FunSuite.scala:15559) at
> org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1423) at
> org.scalatest.FunSSuite.org$scalatest$FunSuiteLike$$super$run(FunSuite.scala:1559)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:204)
> at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:204)
> at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:545) at
> org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$class.run(FuunSuiteLike.scala:204) at
> com.amazon.smt.ec.datapopulator.common.DataFrameOperationsTest.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(DataFrameOperationsTest.scala:21)
> at
> org.scalatest.BBeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:257)
> at
> org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:256)
> at
> com.amazon.smt.ec.datapopulator.common.DattaFrameOperationsTest.run(DataFrameOperationsTest.scala:21)
> at oorg.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner.run(JUnitRunner.scala:99) Caused
> by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at
> org.apache.spaark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.(CompressionCodec.scala:151)

Can someone help me? what am I missing here ?

Comment: can you add pom.xml/sbt here ?